# Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseRecyclerOptions'

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I was making a recycler view. And when I tried to add database-ui of firebase, looks like it didn't work. I got error:

`Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseRecyclerOptions'`

I found that it wasn't imported, and did it manually, but got error:

`Cannot resolve symbol 'firebase'`

I looked for solutions. Updated versions of all firebase dependencies to latest ones for 3 May 2022. But nothing changed.

This is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.3.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.2' 
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

This is import:

```
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I solved it by changing the dependency from:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
```

to:

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.1'
```

No `google.` after `com.`.

Thanks to Sam: https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/c/ZfuZ6QSd-kM?pli=1